# Simulator (Watch) extremely slow network

Tags: swift, performance, alamofire, nsurlsession, watchos

Xcode 8.2.1, fresh iOS 10.2 + WatchKit 3.1 app.

I am having issues with extremely long response times when performing network requests on the Watch simulator (no physical device to test on). Response times can range from 5-6 seconds to 45 seconds (!) on rare occasions.

I've tried using plain `NSURLSession` and `Alamofire` as can be seen below in the `willActivate()` of `InterfaceController`:

```
// URLSession
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    print(response)
}
task.resume()

// Alamofire
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
}
```

The exact same code works as expected with minimal response times when testing on the iOS simulator (e.g. in a `viewDidLoad()` of a `ViewController`).

I don't believe it's a network / Wifi problem since I've tested on two different computers at different locations.

I am aware Apple recommends using background configured sessions on the Watch, however that is because the app might be terminated early by the system and that's the only way the response can be handled, or is it?

Maybe it is a known Watch simulator issue?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with the watch simulator.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Have you filed a bug report? If so I will duplicate it if you add it to http://openradar.me

Comment: @KaneCheshire, I haven't no, cause I wasn't sure it's a bug. I wanted to confirm that first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is!

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread, but thought i'd let you know that Apple says simulator network access being slow is a bug and opened radar 34810194. [More info at the forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88205#266884).